# CSS line break if text is one line, but no break if more than 1 line

Tags: css, responsive-design, line-breaks

I'm trying to produce a CSS line break in scenario 1, but not in scenario 2. In both cases text is dynamically sourced from a database, so I don't know a priori how long the first sentence will be.

Scenario 1:

```
This is the first sentence of a block.
This is the second sentence of the block, which is wide.
```

Scenario 2:

```
This is the first sentence of the next example that
breaks. This is the second sentence of the block, which
is wide.
```

Is this possible with CSS only? I'm currently solving this through JS code running on window resize, but that is slow.

Edit: Clarify that this should work for dynamic text lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set sentences to be blocked in the first scenario and set a fixed width for the text container in the second scenario like so:

```css
.scenario1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.scenario1 span {
  display: block;
}

.scenario2 {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scenario1"><span>This is the first sentence of a block.</span> 
<span>This is the second sentence of the block, which is wide.</span></div>
<br />
<div class="scenario2">This is the first sentence of the next example that breaks. This is the second sentence of the block, which is wide.</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I don't know the length of sentences at design time. Updated the post. I can split sentences on the server side though and put the first one into a separate span.

Comment: So to be sure, in the first scenario, you want to create a line break after each sentence? But in the second scenario, you don't want line breaks after each sentence, just after a certain width. Am I right?

Comment: I want a line break after the first sentence if the first sentence in its entirety occupies one line or less. If it takes more than one line, I want no break.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know before how long the first sentence will be nor how wide the browser window is, so I'll have to adjust this dynamically and was hoping CSS could do the trick here.